# angular ui date with latest jquery ui datepicker reopening IE(11)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, angular-ui-datepicker

I am trying to use the latest angular 1.5.8, jQuery 3 and jQuery UI 1.12 versions together with angular ui date 1.0.1.

These versions combined work fine in chrome / firefox. But now it seems that in IE11 the datepicker keeps reopening after selecting a date.

A very basic fiddle with a failing example:
https://jsfiddle.net/37zt9pj7/

HTML code in the example:

```
<body ng-app="test">
<input type="text" ng-model="datum" ui-date>
</body>
```

And angular module:

```
angular.module('test', ['ui.date']);
```

I've tried many fixes for 'reopening issues' with previous versions, but it looks like these don't work for the current versions.

Related:
https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9125

Has anyone found a fix for this already?

Answer (score 0):

seems like this is a bug in the ui date 1.0.1 version of the library, unrelated to angular/jquery/jquery-ui. Using 1.0.0 solves my issue.

Will close the question, and report a bug for the library.